# Why to use ASP.NET Identity or Form Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a project not very large scale and came to create a system of registration and login. In which cases/projects you might want to use ASP.NET Identity and when you just want to create your own login system, whose creation is much easier?
As a result of Your practice?

Maybe I have to use Form Authenticator?

Comment: _"whose creation is much easier"_ and probably much more insecure.

Answer (score 5):

- Do you want social login (google / facebook / twitter / linkedin / etc)?
- Do you want two-factor authentication?
- Do you require users to confirm an email address as part of registration?
- YOU **DO** WANT TO 1-WAY ENCRYPT THE PASSWORD ...but how?

ASP.NET Identity2 makes doing a lot of these things easier, because they already wrote the code for a lot of this stuff -- password hashing, creating confirmation tokens (for registration / password reset / linking emails to an account), social logins, etc.

Also, @Tim Schmelter makes a very good point in his comment. Security is not easy to get right. When you roll your own registration and login, you are not only making more work for yourself, but you are probably going to leave holes in the registration and login system.

ASP.NET Identity is not an "all or nothing" tool. You can use pieces of it as needed. There is no reason why you can't borrow the password hashing and token generation/validation portions of it, and then use the (non-claims-based) FormsAuthentication to write the cookie. However if you want claims-based authentication and social logins, I would recommend staying away from FormsAuthentication.

Comment: Oh, you have right but the ASP.NET Identity is really difficult to implementation (in my opinion). So.. maybe I can in the big project use for example Visual Studio Template? Is the good pratice?

Comment: @Alder23, if you think ASP.NET Identity is really difficult, have you tried creating a password hashing algorithm? How would you generate confirmation tokens?

Comment: To hash password I using Crypto API. This is not good approach? Maybe you know some step by step tutorial how to create registration and login usgin ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: @Alder23, my point is that your question is primarily opinion-based. If you are confident and feel comfortable doing everything needed to secure the registration and login portions of the app, then have at it. I personally like ASP.NET Identity, but I think using it is less difficult than creating all of this stuff myself. Then again, that's just MY opinion. Also, there are many articles out there on how to use ASP.NET Identity -- it's not as difficult as you may think, once you get to know it. It's not an all-or-nothing tool. You can just use pieces of it as needed.

Comment: Implementing the parts of ASP.NET Identity you need (assuming one doesn't need everything) is not that hard. Hashing a password is not that big of a deal and that is pretty much all the security you need. On the other hand implementing the authentication cookie is quite serious business and something that is very easy to get wrong.